# Snap/Trace to layer in MapInfo without it being selectable?

Tags: mapinfo

Is it possible to snap/trace a layer in MapInfo without it being selectable? I am preparing workspaces for a survey and I don't want the surveyors being able to select the background mapping (they're not too tech-savy) but still be able to trace features from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in MapInfo a layer must be selectable for you to be able to select, trace and get information about it thru the Map window.

You can of course limit the number of layers that are selectable but you then also limit which layers can be traced.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there might actually be another solution to this as well - but it requires some MapBasic programming skills.

You can create a MapBasic tool with a SelChangedHandler that reacts to the selection the user makes. When ever he selects from a layer you don't want him to select from, you unselects everything.

Personally I would find this kind of tool annoying but it might actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst as Peter says there is no way to snap to a non selectable layer, you can hide the fact that objects are selected by removing their selection style in Options->Preferences->Styles. That way your end users won't notice any difference when they click on your background mapping.